# Make link button disable for page load using jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a link_to_function with image tag. I want to disable it (make its image blur n disable click event) for page load. But anothr button named "button 1" is clicked then only it should be enabled. How can i accomplish it?

Css for image with link is

```
.img  
{
opacity:0.4;
filter:alpha(opacity=40); 
}
```

View is ....

```
<%i = 1%>
<div id = "file_<%= i %>" class = "file">
<%= link_to_function image_tag("play_images.png",:width => 30, :height => 30,:align => 'left', :title => 'Play', :id => "img_play#{i}"), :id => "play_#{i}"%>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= link_to_function image_tag("stop_images.png",:width => 30, :height => 30,:align => 'left', :title => 'Stop', :id => "img_stop#{i}",:class => "img"), :id => "stop_#{i}"%>
<%= link_to_function image_tag("fast_fwd.jpeg",:width => 30, :height => 30, :title => 'Fast farword', :id => "img_ff#{i}", :class => "img"), :disabled => 'true',:id => "ff_#{i}"%>

<%= link_to_function image_tag("images.jpeg",:align => 'right'), :id => "close_#{i}"%>
 <div id = "request_<%= i%>" class = "request">
   </div>
 </div>
 <%i = i + 1%>
```

Now, here what i want is initially 2 image button with class "img" will be blured and disabled to, and as i click on button with id "play_#", both button with class "img" will remove their classes and they wll b enabled. So how can i make them disable on load and enable when play button is clicked. My jquery is...

```
   function set_file(id,time,user,node,activity)
    {
     var filename = "";
       filename = user+"_"+node+"_"+activity+"_"+time;

        jQuery("#log_"+id).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#file_"+id).dialog({modal: true, resizable: false, draggable: false,
                 title: "File Content", width: 520,

       });
        jQuery("#play_"+id).click(function(){
          jQuery("#img_stop"+id).removeClass();
          jQuery("#img_ff"+id).removeClass();
                    text="content of text here";
                    delay=500;
                    currentChar=1;
                    destination="[not defined]";
       jQuery.get('/requests/download_log/?filename=' + filename, function(data) {
    });

});
jQuery("#stop_"+id).click(function(){
    jQuery("#img_ff"+id).addClass('img');
    jQuery("#img_stop"+id).addClass('img');
   alert("Stop");
  });
   jQuery("#ff_"+id).click(function(){
  alert("Fast Forward");
  });
 }
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to make it clearer exactly what it is you're trying to do - it's hard to understand.

Comment: if i understood you correctly, you could hide the link by something like style='display:none;' and then show it when button is clicked...!

Comment: your question is unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please describe your problem more exactly, e.g. post some code.

maybe you try to do something like that:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var $button1 = jQuery('#button1');
    var $button2 = jQuery('#button2').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    $button1.click(function() {
        if ($button2.is(':disabled')) {
            $button2.removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $button2.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });

    $button2.click(function() {
        alert('button2 - click');
    });
});​
```

try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/f9F9z/2/

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you have several possibilities here. The most common one is to initially not display the button by using css display:none. You could on document ready set the display to block or remove the css. The same function could be used if you click "button 1".

If there is another method you should post some code so we can see if there is a more appropriate way of doing this.

Comment: I have edited the query please go through with that and let me know what is the issue? I have used "jQuery('#button2').attr('disabled', 'disabled');" but it makes button disable for entire operation.

Comment: First of all, if you still have a problem you shouldn't mark your question as answered. I made a very simple script for your issue: check this 

    http://jsfiddle.net/GdSZM/1/
All this is doing is adding a click event which does nothing to the anchor behind the image. When you press the button the opacity of the image is set to 1, also the cursor is set to pointer and the click event is removed. This leads to a working button. You could also have a 2nd button enabling it again by just calling the function.. hope it helps..

Comment: $("#btn").off('click'); is not working. Program gets terminated and not executing next staement. I m unable to find out this issue.